# What is the reason causing Stackoverflow error when I implement subarray sum in Java using recursive method?

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, sub-array

I am trying to solve the problem set from Lintcode:
Given an integer array, find the start and end index of the sub array that have sum up to zero. 
For example:
Given an array [-3, 1, 2, -3, 4]，return [0, 2] or [1, 3]. 

The code below is NOT optimal answer to this problem, it just was my first try to solve this problem, but I don't know why it's causing Java stackoverflow error and want to figure out, so I decide to post here. I also run the code in Eclipse IDE and it gives me the correct answer.
I implemented this using recursive calls, maybe this is the reason causing stack overflow issue, I am not sure.

Thanks for any help in advance!

```
public ArrayList<Integer> subarraySum(int[] nums) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if (nums == null || nums.length == 0) return list;
    if (nums[0] == 0){
        list.add(0);
        list.add(0);
        return list;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<nums.length; i++){

        calculateSum(i+1, nums, 0-nums[i], list);
        if (list.size() != 0){
            list.add(0, i);
            break;
        }
    }

    return list;
}

private void calculateSum(int start, int[] nums, int target, ArrayList<Integer> list){
    if (start == (nums.length - 1)){
        if (target != nums[start]){
            return;
        }else{
            list.add(start);
            return;
        }
    }else{
        if (target == nums[start]){
            list.add(start);
            return;
        }else{
            calculateSum(start+1, nums, target-nums[start], list);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If eclipse gives you a correct answer what do you want then?

Comment: If you are getting stack overflow, then your recursive function does not have a proper termination condition.  Step through code in debugger with minimal size data.

Comment: Maybe I am seeing it wrong, but does your code work with an array of length 1? Looks to me like it goes straight to the else-else in the calculateSum method (causing then the stack overflow)

Comment: Two comments.  (1) Stepping through with a debugger would enable you to find your problem instantly.  (2) Why on earth would you want to use recursion for a problem that's screaming out to be done iteratively?